# How to use regular expression in fetching data from graphite?

Tags: ruby, graphite

I want to fetch data from different counters from graphite in one single request like:-

```
summarize(site.testing_server_2.triggers_unknown.count,'1hour','sum')&format=json

summarize(site.testing_server_2.requests_failed.count,'1hour','sum')&format=json

summarize(site.testing_server_2.core_network_bad_soap.count,'1hour','sum')&format=json
```

and so on.. 20 more.

But I don't want to fetch

```
summarize(site.testing_server_2.module_xyz_abc.count,'1hour','sum')&format=json
```

in that request how can i do that?

This is what I tried:

```
summarize(site.testing_server_2.*.count,'1hour','sum')&format=json&from=-24hour
```

It gets json data for 'module_xyz_abc' too, but that i don't want.

Comment: I think we need to see code you've written toward solving this, so we can fit a solution into it, rather than write it entirely from scratch for you. As is, it looks like you want to match `/\.module_/` but that doesn't do much good unless we know more. Can you simplify/shorten the URLs you're showing also? As is, they're wasting a lot of visual space without showing much useful.

Comment: @theTinMan, question updated.

Comment: hey! @theTinMan, could you help now?

Comment: @MattSelf could you help here?

Comment: I don't see any code showing what you've tried.

Comment: @theTinMan can you read it again, the last section?

Comment: @theTinMan this time i have mentioned this in bold letters what i tried, can you see this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't use regular expressions per se, but you can use some similar (in concept and somewhat in format) matching techniques available within the Graphite Render URL API.  There are a few ways you can "match" within a target's "bucket" (i.e. between the dots).

### Target Matching

**Asterisk * match**

The asterisk can be used to **match ANY -zero or more- character(s)**.  It can be used to replace the entire bucket (`site.*.test`) or within the bucket (`site.w*t.test`). Here is an example:

```
site.testing_server_2.requests_*.count
```

This would match site.testing_server_2.requests_*failed*.count, site.testing_server_2.requests_*success*.count, site.testing_server_2.requests_*blah123*.count, and so forth.

**Character range [a-z0-9] match**

The character range match is used to match on a single character (`site.w[0-9]t.test`) in the target's bucket and is specified as a range or list.  For example:

```
site.testing_server_[0-4].requests_failed.count
```

This would match on site.testing_server_0.requests_failed.count, site.testing_server_1.requests_failed.count, site.testing_server_2.requests_failed.count, and so forth.

**Value list (group capture) {blah, test, ...} match**

The value list match can be used to match anything in the list of values, in the specified portion of the target's bucket.

```
site.testing_server_2.{triggers_unknown,requests_failed,core_network_bad_soap}.count
```

This would match site.testing_server_2.triggers_unknown.count, site.testing_server_2.requests_failed.count, and site.testing_server_2.core_network_bad_soap.count.  But nothing else, so site.testing_server_2.module_xyz_abc.count would not match.

### Answer

Without knowing all of your bucket values it is difficult to be surgical with the approach (perhaps with a combination of the matching options), so I'll recommend just going with a  **value list match**.  This should allow you to get all of the values in one -somewhat long- request.  For example (and keep in mind you'd need to include all of your values):

```
summarize(site.testing_server_2.{triggers_unknown,requests_failed,core_network_bad_soap}.count,'1hour','sum')&format=json&from=-24hour
```

For more, see [Graphite Paths and Wildcards](https://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/render_api.html#paths-and-wildcards)

Comment: Is it possible to match what's _not_ in a group?

Answer (score 0):

It might a bit late post, but I would say that **the answer using {} could be improved** with **() and | operators**, because the later is more widely compatible regular expression.

Thus, instead of using

`{triggers_unknown,requests_failed,core_network_bad_soap}`
,

try

`(triggers_unknown|requests_failed|core_network_bad_soap)`

.

With the later method we can **capture the value inside ()** with such command as aliasSub, or etc, and it is widely compatible when it comes to regular expression concept.